# User Validation in Java Script using Static Password

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Java Script and recently got a program in JS For Implementing Static Password Protection

Here is my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    User Validation  : 2nd Program
    </title>

    <script "javascript">

    function validate()
    {
    alert(form.username.value)
    alert(document.getelementbyId(username).value);
    alert(form.password.value)
        if(form.username.value == "sample" && form.password.value =="password")
            {
                alert("User Validated ");
                continue();
            }
        else
            {
                alert("Incorrect Username or Password" );
            }

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <text align=center>
    <form name="form" onsubmit="validate()">
    Username <input type="text" name="username" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" maxlength=10 />

    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </text>
    </body>
```

Now , I have defined a username->"sample" by default and password ->"password" by default for user validation .

But whenever after submitting the form resets again without executing the validate function ! 
As am new to JS ignore me for a silly mistake .

Also suggest some best books for Learning JS and JSP from the scratch !

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: This is in no way secure, almost the opposite, but it looks like homework, so that might not matter. Anyway, what are you expecting, the form submits and nothing happens, just as expected as the form submission is not prevented, and there doesn't seem to be a continue() function ?

Comment: @dandavis Am Expecting a Message in an alert box if the user is validated but the form resets !

Comment: @adeneo The Continue function isn't being called because its not entering in the if statement , the form resets ..

Comment: First of all, there is no `continue()` function in that code, secondly, there is no `form` variable, and as such no `form.username`, no `form.username.value`, and there is no variable called `username` either? Where are you getting these names ?

Comment: See , 
1. Continue is defined by JS so there is no need of defining it !


2. There is a form variable : 
 `<form name="form" onsubmit="validate()">
    Username <input type="text" name="username" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" maxlength=10 />

    <input type="submit" />
    </form> `
3. Look at the username field : 

`Username <input type="text" name="username" />`

Comment: for future reference, continue is not a function, it's a statement designed for skipping an iteration in a loop (for / while) and continuing with the next one (as opposed to break, which breaks out of the loop). and form is implicitly declared when you give your form a name.

Comment: As noted, continue is not a function, and as a sidenote, it's a terrible practice to rely on elements being attached to the window object, and it's considered such a no-no that you should be downvoted to -100000 just for doing it.

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso Can you quote that with an example ? ,, It would be better for me to get that !

Comment: Appended to answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `onsubmit="validate()"` to `onsubmit="return validate();"`.

this way, when validate returns false, the form won't submit. you'd also have to change the validate func to return false when the form doesn't validate, the resulting code would be:

```
function validate()
    {
    alert(form.username.value)
    alert(document.getelementbyId(username).value);
    alert(form.password.value)
        if(form.username.value == "sample" && form.password.value =="password")
            {
                alert("User Validated ");
                return true;
            }
        else
            {
                alert("Incorrect Username or Password" );
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Update: continue and break illustrated.

```
while(true) {
    // :loopStart
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if (randomNumber < .5) {
        continue; //skips the rest of the code and goes back to :loopStart
    }
    if (randomNumber >= .6) {
        break; //exits the while loop (resumes execution at :loopEnd)
    }
    alert('value is between .5 and .6');
}
// :loopEnd
```

just in case, :loopStart and :loopEnd aren't special identifiers or anything, they're just comments to help you trace the code better

Comment: That doesn't makes any change to the output its still the same !! i.e. it gets reset !

Comment: You have a typo in one of your alerts. Where it says getelementbyId(username) it should say getElementById('username') (note casing and the use of quotes around username)

Comment: Got the answer I wished for ,, recommend a good book for JS and JSP !

Comment: w3schools.com is a good resource for starting from scratch. also javascript: the definitive guide is a thorough reference of both the language and the DOM tree.